# SQL INSERT based on null values comparison from 2 other tables

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, postgresql

I have two tables for ex:

**Table 1**

```
id code  
1  a  
2  b  
3
```

**Table 2**

```
id code  
4  a  
5  b  
6
```

**Table 3**

```
id id1  
1  4  
2  5
```

I basically want to insert table 3 with the ids of table 1 and table 2 where based on `table1.name = table2.name`.

```
INSERT INTO table3(id,id1)
           SELECT t1.id,t2.id FROM table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.name=t2.name;
```

However table 1 and table 2 has null codes for 3rd row, how will i compare as `null = null` wont work.

Help is appreciated..

Comment: Is it `name` or `code` ?

Comment: I guess that you're not using each and every DBMS listed in your tags...

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `(t1.name IS NULL AND t2.name IS NULL)` test:

```
INSERT INTO table3 (id, id1)
SELECT t1.id, t2.id 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name OR (t1.name IS NULL AND t2.name IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 1):

As I learned a few days ago, MySQL supports a syntax enhancement `<=>` to compare NULLs as equal:

```
INSERT INTO table3(id,id1)
       SELECT t1.id,t2.id 
       FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 
         ON t1.name <=> t2.name;
```

Edit:

[MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Comment: Wow, didn't know that, interesting :) [Here's the reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 0):

use inner join

```
INSERT INTO table3(id,id1) SELECT t1.id, t2.id 
FROM table1 t1 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name OR (t1.name IS NULL AND t2.name IS NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, using nvl() for convert null value to less-used characters.

```
INSERT INTO table3(id,id1)
SELECT t1.id,t2.id
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
WHERE nvl(t1.code,'$$')=nvl(t2.code,'$$');
```

Comment: Or better use `COALESCE` instead of `NVL` which is not proprietary and supported by all DBMSes (including Oracle)

Comment: @dnoeth I didn't know about `COALESCE`. Thanks for your advice.